# Calculating the maximum size of derived classes

Tags: c++, uml

We have a My_list class that has a list of pointers to Abstract_things.  To optimize on memory usage, all derived Things use one memory pool that is established with the "new and delete" stereotype.  In order to size the pool properly during the initization of the application, the builder figures out which Thing is the biggest and sizes the pool based on that.

The design dilemma is that if a new Thing is added to the model, (represented with the red Thing_4), the designer has to know to go over to Builder to adjust the logic.  I have observed that it was hard enough for our team to remember to do this (about half our Things weren’t considered in the Builder).  I’m very concerned that future generations will overlook this.

My question is how can I improve this?  It would be wonderful if in the act of creating a Thing_4 class, all that max_size stuff automagically got handled.  I can’t think of a way though.

Note: Reviewing my picture I realize there's a mistake.  The last line in the code-box should read Abstract_thing::set_max_pool_size(max_size, max_number).

Edit: I can't figure out how to display a picture.  Everything looks good in the preview window, but when published it's not there.  Any help?

Edit: To give a little bit more background, this is part of a design for an embedded application in a safety-critical system.  We are allowed to allocate memory off the heap when the application is initializing, but after we exit that initialization phase, NO dynamic memory can be allocated.  Attempting to do so crashes the application.  Therefore, we program to the largest sizes and the maximum number of instances we use.  Having one pool that contains enough space for all derived objects is the better approach over having a pool for each derived object.

[alt text http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/4470/designproblemof1.png](http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/4470/designproblemof1.png)

Comment: You will need at least 15 reputation points to post an image. I suggest to use a free image server for now and just post the URL.

Comment: Could you explain why the embedded constraint causes a problem?  The solutions given by various people use registry of sorts and that registry gets handled at initialization time.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**: ok ... the embedded system requirement changes things somewhat.

You could use a class to register the derived classes automatically, and then added a static instance of this class to each derived class.  You still have to remember to do this though, but at least it is self contained in a single place.

Something like:

```
template<class T>
class RegisterPoolClass
{
public:
    RegisterPoolClass() { init_pool.Register(sizeof(T)); }
};

class Thing_1 : public Abstract_Thing
{
   static RegisterPoolClass<Thing_1> sInitializer;
    ...
};

RegisterPoolClass<Thing_1> Thing_1::sInitializer;
```

You could use a macro to encapsulate the code needed in each derived class in that same way ATL does.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the first post, I'm having problems displaying the accompanying image.  If anyone can give some help there, it might clear up questions.

I'll edit the OP to give some additional insight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand this correctly, but what is stopping you from having a build step which enumerates all the derived classes, estimates their sizes whatever way you use now to calculate the size of your things, and find the biggest one?

Comment: If you could see the attached picture, that's exactly what we're currently doing.  The problem is that in the future if another derived class is added, the logic has to be reopened and adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

grep for classes, build a app that tests all sizes and fails if they messed up.

```
echo '#include"head"' > out.cpp
grep "class \w+ : TheClass" *.cpp | sed  "s/.*class \(\w\)+ : TheClass.*/assert(sizeof($1) <= MAX_SIZE); >> out.cpp
echo '#include"tail"' >> out.cpp
gcc out.cpp
./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

AbstractThing.h

```
#ifndef ABSTRACT_THING
#define ABSTRACT_THING
class AbstractThing
{
private:
    static  size_t                  maxChildSize;
    static  bool                    maxChildLock;
    static  std::vector<type_info>  validChildren;

    static size_t   getMaxChildSize()
    {
        maxChildLock    = true;
        return maxChildSize;
    }
public:
    template<typename T>
    static  void setChildSize()
    {
        // This is to stop registering things after getMaxChildSize()
        // has been called. This check is only needed during testing
        if (maxChildLocked)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
        maxChildSize    = std::max(maxChildSize,sizeof(T));
        validChildren.push_back(typeid T);
    }
    template<typename T>
    static bool testValidType()
    {
        // While testing call this method.
        // Don't call in production to speed things up.

        // Only registered children will be allowed to get memory.
        // Or maybe generate a warning in the log if it fails.
        return validChildren.find(typeid T) != validChildren.end();
    }
};
template<typename T>
class RegisterAbsoluteThing
{
public:
    RegisterAbsoluteThing()
    {
        AbstractThing::setChildSize<T>();
    }
};
#endif
```

Thing1.h

```
#ifndef THING_1
#define THING_1

#include "AbstractThing.h"
class Thing1: public AbstractThing
{
};

namespace
{
    // Because this is in an anonymous namespace
    // It does not matter how many times different files it is included
    // This will then all be registered at startup before main.
    RegisterAbsoluteThing<Thing1>   RegisterAsValidThing1;

    // All class that derive from AbstractThing should have this block.
    // Any that do not that try and use the pool will cause the tests to fail.
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use CTAGS or a similar parser to extract the names of all derived classes and use that to auto-generate your init_pool implementation?